# How to call a custom method with arguments in the models.py from views.py

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views, django-1.9

I have this example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Some fields...
    price = models.FloatField()

    def calculate(self, number):
        return self.price * number
```

In the views:

```
def whatever(request, any_number):
    m = MyModel.objects.all()
    c = m.calculate(any_number)

    # More code...
```

It's a really easy example because I want to do something similar, so how can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: In an unrelated comment, you probably want to use a DecimalField instead of a FloatField for saving prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in a `for` loop, since `m` is an array of objects:

```
for item in m:
     result = item.calculate(any_number)
    # do some stuff with the result
```

Comment: That, or define the method in a custom manager. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/